# Corpus analysis with python

Tags: python, nlp, tokenize

I'm a new student of natural language processing and I have a task regarding simple corpus analysis. Given an input file (MovieCorpus.txt) we are assigned to compute the following statistics:

1. Number of sentences, tokens, types (lemmas)
2. Distribution of sentence length, types, POS

```
import nltk
import spacy as sp
from nltk import word_tokenize

# Setting Spacy Modelsp
nlp = sp.load('en_core_web_sm')

# Movie Corpus
with open ('MovieCorpus.txt','r') as f:
    read_data = f.read().splitlines()


# Tokenize, POS, Lemma
tokens = []
lemma = []
pos = []

for doc in nlp.pipe(read_data):

    if doc.is_parsed:
        tokens.append([n.text for n in doc])
        lemma.append([n.lemma_ for n in doc])
        pos.append([n.pos_ for n in doc])
    else:
        tokens.append(None)
        lemma.append(None)
        pos.append(None)


ls = len(read_data)
print("The amount of sentences is %d:" %ls)

lt = len(tokens)
print("The amount of tokens is %d:" %lt)

ll = len(lemma)
print("The amount of lemmas is %d:" %ll)
```

This is attempt at answering those questions but since the file is very large (>300.000 sentences) it takes forever to analyze. Is there anything I did wrong? Should I rather use NLTK instead of spacy?

Comment: I would suggest that you make a dataframe out of your `read_data` and use the `apply()` function to tokenize the text. That should speed up the process. In addition, you can also import `sent_tokenize` from nltk in order to tokenize by sentences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import nltk
from nltk import word_tokenize

# Movie Corpus
with open ('MovieCorpus.txt','r') as f:
    read_data = f.read().splitlines()

df = pd.DataFrame({"text": read_data}) # Assuming your data has no header 

data = data.head(10) 
w_tokenizer = nltk.tokenize.WhitespaceTokenizer()
lemmatizer = nltk.stem.WordNetLemmatizer()

def lemmatize_text(text):
    return [lemmatizer.lemmatize(w) for w in w_tokenizer.tokenize(text)]

data['lemma'] = data.text.apply(lemmatize_text)
data["tokens"] = data.text.apply(nltk.word_tokenize)
data["posR"] =  data.tokens.apply(lambda x: nltk.pos_tag(x))
tags = [[tag for word, tag in _] for _ in data["posR"].to_list()]
data["pos"] =  tags

print(data)
```

From here on you should be able to do all other tasks by yourself.